# Can I use the ink from the Photosmart inkjet cartridges for my dip calligraphy pens?

Tags: painting, calligraphy, ink

My Canon All-In-One Photosmart printer can't be repaired and I still have ink in the cartridges. Can I use the ink from the Photosmart inkjet cartridges for my dip calligraphy pens or with paint brushes?

Comment: If they're otherwise junk, you should try it and let us know.  I susoect the answer is yes.  You may need to dilute them and knowing what with could be tricky.  Breaking in to the cartridges can be awkward and potentially messy

Answer (score 5):

Yes, inkjet ink works with brushes. It's thinner than the usual ink for dip pens, but give it a try. I haven't broken open cartridges to get it, but used the ink from a refill kit. Because they're pure, primary colours, you can theoretically mix any other colour from them, just as the printer does. You can certainly get strong, saturated shades.